# Proving $K[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field. I'm trying to prove that $A=K[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is a Dedekind domain.

I can prove that $A$ is noetherian (since $K[x,y]$ is noetherian) and that $A$ is a domain (since $xy-1$ is irreducible in $K[x,y]$).

To prove that $A$ is not a field, I'm trying to exhibit a non-zero prime ideal, but I can't find it.

To prove that $A$ is integrally closed and that every prime is maximal, I have no idea.

Comment: Hint : $A \cong K[x,x^{-1}]$, this description can be useful.

Comment: @user171326, your idea is to argue that $A\simeq S^{-1}(k[x])$, where $S:=\{1,x,x^2,...\}$, so that $A$ is the localization of a Dedekind domain, therefore Dedekind. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localization of a Dedekind domain is a Dedekind domain. Use universal property of localization to prove that given ring is indeed a localization of a PID. Therefore a PID, and not just a Dedekind Domain.

Comment: Your answer isn't right. $ K [x, y] $ is not a PID.

Comment: @Xam I think they mean that $K[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong K[t][t^{-1}]$, so we are localizing the Dedekind domain (PID even) $K[t]$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent that makes sense. Otoh, I think the answerer should be a little more clear with his/her wording.